# Why do we not use an indirection operator when trying to access element of an array using a pointer?

Tags: c

I have a program that asks for a number of students and then for each of their first, last names and studentID. I'm attempting to print each of the values that are stored in the array of students. However, I get an error on the line `printf("%d\n", *(students+i)->studentID);` of `Indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)`.

I tried changing the line to `printf("%d\n", (students+i)->studentID);` and it seems to work. Why is this happening and why don't we need to do this for the print statements above that are printing characters? Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Students {
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
    int studentID;
} Student;

void printRecords(Student *students, int size){

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("%c\n", *(students+i)->firstName);  // prints
        printf("%c\n", *(students+i)->lastName);   // prints
        printf("%d\n", *(students+i)->studentID);  // does not print

     }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int number_of_records;

    printf("Please enter the number of records you would like to add:\n");
    scanf("%d", &number_of_records);

    Student *S;
    S = (Student*)malloc(sizeof(Student) * number_of_records);

    for(int i = 0; i < number_of_records; i++){
        printf("First name of student %d\n", i+1);
        scanf("%s/n", S[i].firstName);

        printf("Last name of student %d\n", i+1);
        scanf("%s/n", S[i].lastName);

        printf("StudentID of student %d\n", i+1);
        scanf("%d/n", &S[i].studentID);
    }

    printRecords(S, number_of_records);
}
```

Comment: This is the difference between `(*s).firstName` and `s->firstName`.

Comment: `printf("%c\n", *(students+i)->firstName);` <<-- students is undefined here. [also: you'd probably want to use`"%s\n"` here]

Comment: You didn't show where is the `students` array defined (you use it in function `printRecords()`).

Comment: @wildplasser My apologies, I've added it.

Comment: The correct way to access the `i`th element of array `a` is `a[i]`. Please don't use `*(a+i)`, ever. Write `students[i].name` etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*(students+i)->studentID` is an equivalent of  `*((students+i)->studentID)`

You try to dereference the integer and you get the compile error.

The first compiles ok because

`*(students+i)->firstName`  is the same as  `*((students+i)->firstName)` and the member `firstName` is an array which decays to the pointer of the `char *` type. You can of course dereference pointers.

Answer (score 1):

`->` is an (implicit) indirection operator -- `a->b` is the same as `(*a).b`.  So when you write

```
*(students+i)->studentID
```

that's the same as

```
*(*(students+i)).studentID
```

with TWO indirection operations.

Answer (score -1):

You **can** use the indirection operator here, but then you use the member operator `.` instead of `->`:

```
printf("%d\n", (*(students+i)).studentID);
```

This is semantically the same as

```
printf("%d\n", (students+i)->studentID);
```